# Sum up data per row based on dates

Tags: excel

I've got some data as seen below from row 2-7.

I would like to combine all the data from **previous months** **into one row**, so from the picture below, I would like to combine the data from 05/05/2014-07/09/2014, but leave the most **recent month** **'s data untouched** and not combined. So I need to sum up the data in column G and column H, for rows 2-4, the other columns don't matter.

Rows 11-14 is what I would like to achieve. How would I do that (macro or otherwise)?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AhrA.jpg]

Comment: Yes, it will always be shown. But sometimes there could be more or less data (i.e. maybe only F2:F5, or F2:F20), depending on how many transactions. I need all the previous months transactions summed up into one row, and only the current month's transactions listed out

Comment: The data is from a query, if there is no entries that month its fine because I won't run need to make the report.

 Sorry, 74.2911 is just a random number, was just using it to illustrate an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this will get you started:

```
Sub Summary()
    Dim FirstDataRow As Long
    Dim LastDataRow As Long
    Dim DataRow As Long
    Dim cDates As Long
    Dim cAmounts As Long
    Dim CutoffDate As Date
    Dim EarliestOldDate As Date
    Dim LatestOldDate As Date
    Dim SumOfOld As Long
    Dim OldMonthsRow As Long
    Dim OffSetToSummaryTable As Long
    Dim InputRow As Long
    Dim OutputRow As Long
    Dim TheDate As Date
    Dim TheAmount As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' INITIALIZE
    ' Assume we're operating on the activesheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ' Assume data starts in Row 2
    FirstDataRow = 2

    ' Assume data is a contiguous block
    LastDataRow = ws.Range("F" & CStr(FirstDataRow)).End(xlDown).Row

    ' Assume 3 empty rows between input and summary table
    OffSetToSummaryTable = 3

    ' Calculate row where sum of old months goes
    OldMonthsRow = LastDataRow + OffSetToSummaryTable + 1

    ' Calculate the cutoff date = first date of current month
    CutoffDate = DateSerial(2015, 1, 1)
    ' CutoffDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)

    ' Column where dates are
    cDates = 6

    ' Column where amounts are
    cAmounts = 7

    ' Initialize earliest and latest old dates, and sum of old
    EarliestOldDate = DateSerial(3000, 12, 31)  ' Way out in the future
    LatestOldDate = DateSerial(1904, 1, 1)      ' Way back in the past
    SumOfOld = 0


    ' PROCESS THE DATA
    OutputRow = OldMonthsRow
    For InputRow = FirstDataRow To LastDataRow
        TheDate = ws.Cells(InputRow, cDates)
        TheAmount = ws.Cells(InputRow, cAmounts)

        If TheDate >= CutoffDate Then
            ' Add at the bottom of the summary table
            OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
            ws.Cells(OutputRow, cDates).Formula = TheDate
            ws.Cells(OutputRow, cAmounts).Formula = TheAmount
        Else
            ' Update results for previous months
            EarliestOldDate = IIf(TheDate < EarliestOldDate, TheDate, EarliestOldDate)
            LatestOldDate = IIf(TheDate > LatestOldDate, TheDate, LatestOldDate)
            SumOfOld = SumOfOld + TheAmount
        End If

    Next InputRow

    ' WRITE RESULTS TO SUMMARY ROW
    ws.Cells(OldMonthsRow, cDates).Formula = Format(EarliestOldDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " - " & Format(LatestOldDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    ws.Cells(OldMonthsRow, cAmounts).Formula = SumOfOld

    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! However, I also need the other fields from B12:E14 and H12:H14 together with the data that is generated in Column F and G. As in -- for the current month I need all the data in each row pasted into the "OffSetToSummaryTable", not just Column F and G. Any ideas?

Comment: Frankie, what don't you try modifying the sample code. I think you can figure out how it works and then make changes so that is functions the way you like.